# Filtering a model with query parameters

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my backend I have a list of available phone numbers: `/api/phonenumbers`. And I have a model for that: `App.Phonenumber`. I can get all my phone numbers with `App.Phonenumber.find();`

Now I would like to filter the list of phonenumbers, and get only those in a given country / city. The backend is able to perform this filtering by receiving a `/api/phonenumbers?country=DE&city=Berlin` query string.

1. How can I extend my `Phonenumber` model to be able to pass these query string parameters?
2. How can I perform a `find` using those query parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe doing something like this could be sufficient for your use case if `city` and `country` are properties on your `Phonenumber` model:

```
App.Phonenumber.find({city: 'Berlin', country: 'DE'});
```

This should produce a similar URL like:

```
?country=DE&city=Berlin
```

Hope it helps.